# How can I do load test with JMS support using Citrus testing framework

Tags: citrus-framework

I am doing load-test using citrus framework with reference of Http load testing sample in Citrus framework document but I am not able to doing load-test, it is not working.Any body please help me on that.Advance thanks.

Comment: what problems do you have? any errors, logs, stack traces?

Comment: Hi Christoph Thanks for your response, Now I am able to do load test with JMS support 
 by using this Annotation @Test(invocationCount = 250, threadPoolSize = 25), But when i give count in thousands it is  taking some time to put messages in Queue.Is There any Way to reduce time and put messages quickly in MQ.